# Как извлечь текст из .doc файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Требуется извлечь текст из .doc файла. Как и при помощи какой библиотеки я могу осуществить данную задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сергей Андреев. Для того, чтобы получить данные из файла doc, Вы можете использовать несколько подходов.

1. Использование библиотеки olefile
   Пример:

```
import olefile


ole = olefile.OleFileIO('./Путь_к_файлу/файл.doc') //путь к Вашему файлу.
print(ole.openstream('WordDocument').read().decode("utf-16", "ignore"))

//Декодирование данных из бинарной системы. (При многократном изменении файла - могут возникать проблемы символов кодировки. В этом случае используйте параметр ignore или replace.
```

Так же Вы можете изначально обработать данные при помощи регулярного выражения, по латинским и русским символам, а так же числам.

2. Установить в систему и использовать antiword

```
 import os
input_word_file = "1.doc"
output_text_file = "output_file.txt"
os.system('antiword %s > %s' % (input_word_file, output_text_file))
//Далее работать с текстом в файле output_file.txt
```

3. Использовать библиотеку ezodf

   Примеры можете посмотреть [Тут](https://pypi.org/project/ezodf/)

Comment: olefile не работает. Сейчас создал девственно чистый doc документ, и получил абсолютно туже ошибку

Comment: @Сергей Андреев я не увреен, что Вы говорите честно. Пример рабочий, запускал у себя Ваш файл успешно.Данные получил.

Comment: https://pastenow.ru/7eb5a291d4da51df7412c04f079902cb

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста весь Ваш код на pastebin

Comment: 1. В чате Вас нет. 2. Это весь код. 3. Выкладывать не буду, Вы же прям уверены что olefile не работает. https://pastenow.ru/fed66bac4f7b940e30a77b20e59399b2   4. Подозреваю, что суть вопроса не разобраться в ситуации, а какая-то другая.

Answer (score 0):

Библиотека textract

```
import textract
text = textract.process("path/to/file.extension")
```

Библиотека docx2txt

```
import docx2txt
my_text = docx2txt.process("test.docx")
print(my_text)
```

Библиотека docx

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document("zen_of_python.docx")
result = [p.text for p in doc.paragraphs]
```

Также doc/docx это зазипованный xml.

Формат doc это бинарный формат без открытого содержания. Соответственно нет понятного механизма для его чтения.

Вот пример перевода doc в txt Установить pywin32.

```
import win32com.client

app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

try:

    wb = app.Documents.Open('d:/test/test.doc')
    doc = app.ActiveDocument

    with open('out.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-16') as f:
        f.write(doc.Content.Text)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    app.Quit()
```

Может быть лучше пересохранить в docx?

Comment: Меня интересует именно .doc файлы. На сколько я знаю, docx2text не работает с .doc файлами.

Comment: Выдаёт ошибку: `KeyError: "There is no item named 'word/document.xml' in the archive"`

Comment: в docx выдаёт ошибку: `ValueError: file '1.doc' is not a Word file, content type is 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.themeManager+xml'`

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/decalage/olefileio_pl/wiki/API  или можно использовать antiword пример: import os
input_word_file = "input_file.doc"
output_text_file = "output_file.txt"
os.system('antiword %s > %s' % (input_word_file, output_text_file)) Есть ещё библиотека ezodf

Comment: Я прмвел 3 варианта, один должен сработать.

Comment: @becouse `textract.exceptions.ShellError: The command `antiword 1.doc` failed with exit code 127`

Comment: @Denis640Kb Каким образом можно извлечь текст используя библиотеку olefile?

Comment: @СергейАндреев ole = olefile.OleFileIO('./Путь к файлу/file.doc')         print(ole.openstream('WordDocument').read())    Только не забывайте, что doc - это бинарный файл. И надо перевести это в удобочитаемый вид потом. Пример - 
print(ole.openstream('WordDocument').read().decode('utf-16').encode('utf-8'))

Comment: @Denis640Kb если нужно вывести через print, то `.encode('utf-8')` не нужно.

Comment: @Denis640Kb вот код: ole = olefile.OleFileIO('1.doc') print(ole.openstream('WordDocument').read().decode('utf-16')) вот ошибка: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 6278-6279: illegal encoding

Comment: @СергейАндреев, ну что же Вы. В сообщении указаны примеры. Вот в какой кодировке у Вас имеется doc в таком и декодируйте.

Comment: @Denis640Kb какая стандартная кодировка у word документа?

Comment: @СергейАндреев стандартная кодировка обычно unicode, но всё зависит от того, какой ОС Вы пользуетесь и какие параметры файла были установлены.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Ничего не выходит. Вот файл который нужно прочесть: https://yadi.sk/i/HiZOoK8BcQuBGQ

Comment: @СергейАндреев видно совсем сложно.  Добавил ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102713/discussion-between---and-denis640kb).